# Disable loading default side.css in Yii2

Tags: css, yii2

I'm starting a new project with Yii2 based on the default example-Welcome-to-yii page. In this example-project, the css file from web/css/site.css is loaded.

But looking in index.php views/layout/main.php, views/site/index.php an the related controller/action, I can't find the place, where the site.css is registered.
So how to remove the registration in order to remove that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site.css  registration  is in yourapplication\asset\AppAsset.php

see this

> ```
>     class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
>     {
>         public $basePath = '@webroot';
>         public $baseUrl = '@web';
>         public $css = [
>             'css/site.css',
>         ];
>         public $js = [
>         ];
>         public $depends = [
>             'yii\web\YiiAsset',
>             'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
>         ];
>     }
> ```